# How to get iframe address in geckofx?

Tags: c#, iframe, webbrowser-control, geckofx

How do I get same information about iframe like in browser properties when you right-click the element but programmatically? I need Address and Referring URL.

[image: iframe properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the frame by name of by tag name (both return a collection and require indexer or linq).

From there, you can access the properties, e.g. Src is the url for the frame.

```
GeckoFrameElement frame = this.Document.GetElementsByTagName("frame")[0] as GeckoFrameElement;
var address =  frame.Src;
```